# How to access child's attribute in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Micropost has content that I want in the index (@user.micropost.content). I can do this in the show but not in index.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My user_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end

def show
  @user  = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.microposts
end
```

Comment: in index you have multiple users not a single user, do you want to fetch all microposts for all users?

Comment: Yes. I want to fetch all microposts for all users

Comment: will you use each micropost with it's user? or do you want one huge array of microposts?

Comment: I want to use each micropost with it's user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a [little eager loading to avoid N+1 queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

```
def index
  @users = User.includes(:microposts).all
end
```

Then in the view you just loop normally and you'll be able to access the object

```
@users.each do |user|
  user.microposts.each do |micropost|
    micropost
  end
end
```

Comment: You just saved my day! Thanks. By the way, using only micropost was displaying memory addresses. Doing micropost.content worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code in your users controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.includes(:microposts).all
end
```

And in your index page you show the microposts using:

```
<% @user.microposts do |micropost| %>
  <p><%= micropost.title%></p>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to use your users' microposts in the view and is also a good practice because the query in the database for the microposts will be executed only once.

Comment: two queries will be executed not one, one for all users and one for all microposts, check the guide `The above code will execute just 2 queries, as opposed to 11 queries in the previous case`

Comment: Yes Mohammad, 1 query for the users and another one for theirs microposts. You're correct! I was referring to the microposts query in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through `@users = User.all` and access the microposts from each user that way.

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @users.each do |user|
    current_users_microposts = user.microposts
    # your code here
  end
end
```

Not sure what your requirements are but you can make an array and append each group of `user.microposts` onto that array as well, in order to have all of them in one variable.